# Sharepoint DateTime control, how to call client side as well as server side on datechanged

Tags: datetime, sharepoint-2010

I am having a datetime control in sharepoint custom webpart

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="txtUKdtofAdm" LocaleId="2057" DateOnly="True"
OnValueChangeClientScript="validateControlsUK();" AutoPostBack="true" 
OnDateChanged="txtUKdtofAdm_OnDateChanged"></SharePoint:DateTimeControl>
```

I want to call a js as well as server side function on date changed.I have done as above but, client side function does not execute. can anyone help me in order to get this workin wherein if a date is changed than both js on client side and onchange server side event should work.

In my case only server side is getting fired.

Kindly help. thank you in advance

Comment: take your `validateControlsUK()`; and put `alert('Hello');` see if alert work or not. if it work there is chance that
your function can not compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the solution to this.

I removed `AutoPostBack="true"` and in javascript I used
`__doPostBack('<%= txtUKdtofAdm.Controls[0].ClientID %>', '');`
which forces a postback which in turn fires `OnDateChanged="txtUKdtofAdm_OnDateChanged"`